# Why would wsl use the wrong distro from the command line on occasion?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

For instance here is the output from a command line session running a simple command in wsl in which it "chooses" the wrong distribution until I shutdown wsl and retry.

```
PS D:\wslsandbox> wsl -l -v        
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu                 Running         2
  mikeenv                Stopped         2
  tam                    Stopped         2
  docker                 Stopped         2
  java17                 Stopped         2
  pedro                  Stopped         2
  docker-desktop         Stopped         2
  docker-desktop-data    Stopped         2
  pedro3                 Running         2
  docker2                Stopped         2
PS D:\wslsandbox> wsl.exe -d pedro3 cat /etc/system-release
/bin/bash: /etc/system-release: No such file or directory
PS D:\wslsandbox> wsl.exe --shutdown
PS D:\wslsandbox> wsl.exe -d pedro3 cat /etc/system-release
Amazon Linux release 2 (Karoo)
PS D:\wslsandbox>
```

the command (wsl.exe -d pedro3 cat /etc/system-release) has different results depending on some "state" the subsystem gets into until it's shutdown.
This happens to me fairly often but I am starting and stopping distros pretty frequently trying to develop something that utilizes wsl.

Here is a case when what ever disto starts first, is the only one you can get to:

```
PS D:\wslsandbox> wsl.exe -l -v
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu                 Stopped         2
  mikeenv                Stopped         2
  tam                    Stopped         2
  docker                 Stopped         2
  java17                 Stopped         2
  pedro                  Stopped         2
  pedro3                 Stopped         2
  docker-desktop         Stopped         2
  docker-desktop-data    Stopped         2
  docker2                Stopped         2
PS D:\wslsandbox> wsl.exe -d Ubuntu cat /etc/system-release
cat: /etc/system-release: No such file or directory
PS D:\wslsandbox> wsl.exe -d pedro3 cat /etc/system-release
cat: /etc/system-release: No such file or directory
PS D:\wslsandbox> wsl.exe -l -v
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu                 Stopped         2
  mikeenv                Stopped         2
  tam                    Stopped         2
  docker                 Stopped         2
  java17                 Stopped         2
  pedro                  Stopped         2
  pedro3                 Stopped         2
  docker-desktop         Stopped         2
  docker-desktop-data    Stopped         2
  docker2                Stopped         2
PS D:\wslsandbox> wsl.exe -d pedro3 cat /etc/system-release
Amazon Linux release 2 (Karoo)
PS D:\wslsandbox> wsl.exe -d Ubuntu cat /etc/system-release
Amazon Linux release 2 (Karoo)
```

Another session where the wslg distro (which isn't listed when doing a wsl -l -v) is the only distro I can use until I shutdown:

```
C:\>wsl -d Ubuntu
wslg [ /mnt/c ]$ exit
logout

C:\>wsl -d pedro
wslg [ /mnt/c ]$ exit
logout

C:\>wsl -d pedro2
wslg [ /mnt/c ]$ exit
logout

C:\>wsl -d pedro2 id
uid=1000(wslg) gid=1000(wslg) groups=1000(wslg)

C:\>wsl -d pedro id
uid=1000(wslg) gid=1000(wslg) groups=1000(wslg)

C:\>wsl -d Ubuntu id
uid=1000(wslg) gid=1000(wslg) groups=1000(wslg)

C:\>wsl -l -v
  NAME        STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu      Running         2
  mikeenv     Stopped         2
  java17_2    Stopped         2
  tam         Stopped         2
  pedro3      Stopped         2
  docker      Stopped         2
  pedro2      Stopped         2
  pedro4      Running         2
  pedro       Stopped         2
  docker2     Stopped         2

C:\>wsl -d mikeenv id
uid=1000(wslg) gid=1000(wslg) groups=1000(wslg)

C:\>wsl --shutdown

C:\>wsl -d mikeenv id
uid=1000(mdoyle) gid=1000(mdoyle) groups=1000(mdoyle)

C:\>wsl -d pedro id
uid=1620(lawson) gid=1620(lawson) groups=1620(lawson)

C:\>wsl -d pedro2 id
uid=1620(lawson) gid=1620(lawson) groups=1620(lawson)

C:\>wsl -d Ubuntu id
uid=1000(mdoyle) gid=1000(mdoyle) groups=1000(mdoyle),4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom),25(floppy),27(sudo),29(audio),30(dip),44(video),46(plugdev),117(netdev),36257(docker)
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User!  A few questions - (a) Do you have Systemd enabled in any of those distributions?  I can't see how that might break it at first glance, but I just ran into a *separate* weird Systemd problem while attempting to reproduce this (which I couldn't).  (b) What is your `wsl --version`?

Comment: None that I have installed have systemd enabled, I don't know about the docker distros, I'm not using docker desktop at the moment, I'm thinking of uninstalling that and seeing if my problems go away. PS D:\wslsandbox> wsl --version
WSL version: 1.2.5.0
Kernel version: 5.15.90.1
WSLg version: 1.0.51
MSRDC version: 1.2.3770
Direct3D version: 1.608.2-61064218
DXCore version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows version: 10.0.22621.2134
PS D:\wslsandbox>

Comment: Hmm - I doubt Docker has anything to do with it, but having no clue what's going on with this, what do I know? ;-).  I'd like to get some better verification of the actual problem.  Can you repeat the test above but using `wsl -d pedro3 cat /etc/os-release` (and the same for `-d Ubuntu`?

Comment: I cannot make it occur on demand but it seems to happen pretty often. What seems to make things go "haywire" is when I have an instance (distro) of wsl running a fairly lengthy java compile build and I start another instance (distro). I see things like, every wsl command hangs, or the other instance (distro) exits for no reason, etc. At this moment I see that the "selected" distro is the wslg distro? I wouldn't even know how to get into that distro if I wanted to: PS D:\wslsandbox> wsl -d Ubuntu
wslg [ /mnt/d/wslsandbox ]$ cd
wslg [ ~ ]$

Comment: Can you clarify, *'the "selected" distro is the wslg distro?'*  I don't see a WSLg distro in your `wsl -l -v` list above.  Re:*"every wsl command hangs"* - I have definitely gotten into that state before.  The next time it happens, I'll see what a `wsl -d <other_distro> cat /etc/os-release` returns.  That might be the key to reproducing.  Unfortunately, if that's the issue your seeing, there's likely no good solution other than figuring out why WSL is crashing in the first place and opening a ticket on Github for that :-/

Comment: By "selected" I mean what ever disto that wsl decides is the only one I can access no matter what -d I put on the command line. I'll edit my question again and add another session using the 'id' command. I can tell I'm in the wrong distro by the command prompt but using the id command it's clear that I'm in the wrong distro. I have uninstalled docker-decktop and you were right nothing really changed.

Comment: I think it has something to do with VSCode. I can run a large build in one distro and access other distros, create new distros, even start another build in another distro, all seems to work as long as I never start VSCode, with VSCode running those things I mentioned doing will inventible drop me into this "one distro" mode, and I'm not even remoting into a wsl distro with it.

Answer (score 1):

I think I tracked it down. For whatever reason if I pasted this series of commands into a powershell prompt I could repeatably get the issue to occur:

```
wsl --unregister pedro
wsl --shutdown
sleep 5
Start-Process -FilePath "taskkill" -ArgumentList "/f /im wslservice.exe" -Verb RunAs
sleep 5
wsl.exe --import pedro d:\pedro D:\imagecache\202362aa398ce6c410e395b44d710aea
wsl -l -v
wsl -d pedro echo "hello"
wsl -d pedro echo "hello"
sleep 20
wsl -d pedro
```

Note there is an elevated privilege command in the mix so I was prompted for that but it would continue.
Playing with this I changed out the image I was importing to different images and noticed that it was only happening on the one image so I deduced this was image related. The questionable image had this in the wsl.conf:

```
[boot]
command="sudo /usr/sbin/sysctl -p"
```

I created a new image without this entry and I no longer can repeat the issue pasting in the commands above into powershell.
I'm not sure if that call is necessary or even effective in a wsl distro?? but I believe it was meant to apply some adjustments made to the /etc/sysctl.conf file like:

```
fs.inotify.max_queued_events=17408
fs.inotify.max_user_instances=256
fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288
```

Thank you @NotTheDr01ds for the help!

Comment: I spoke too soon. the problem persists.